# How to highlight only the 1st degree edges with visOptions?

Tags: r, visnetwork

I am visualizing a highly connected network. I would like the user to be able to highlight only a selected node, the first degree nodes it connects to, and the edges of these connections.

I manage to do this but my code also highlight the edges between the first degree connections, which I do not want.

The code I've used is:

```r
netw %>% visIgraph(layout="layout_in_circle", idToLabel = TRUE)  %>% visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled=T, algorithm="hierarchical", degree=list(from=0, to=1)))
```

Example of a network that reproduces the effect:
10 -> 12 ; 10 -> 32; 32 -> 12

In the graph, I've clicked on node 10. It highlights the nodes 12 and 32 and the edges to them. But it also highlights the edge from 12 to 32. How to avoid this?